# Attribute Value Selection in SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml

Why can't I filter results on the attribute value rather than the index?

Something like this fails.

```
foreach ($portfolio->clientGroup[$id]->client['name=foo']->src as $src) {
   echo $src . '<br />';
}
```

But this works.

```
foreach ($portfolio->clientGroup[$id]->client[0]->src as $src) {
   echo $src . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: X-Ref: [SimpleXML: Selecting Elements Which Have A Certain Attribute Value (Jun 2009)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/992450/367456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work because SimpleXML is a lightweight implementation. Plus, you can't assume **anything** to work unless you have a specification.

You are looking for the [xpath function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-element-xpath.php) of `SimpleXMLElement` objects, i.e.:

```
foreach ($portfolio->clientGroup[$id]->xpath("client[@name='foo']/src") as $src) {
   echo $src . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Counter question: Are you sure that "name" isn't a child of <client>, instead of an attribute?

Comment: Yes ("Why can't I filter results on the *attribute value* rather than the index?")

Comment: Oops. Seems my browser font is too small. ;-) Whatever, I added an XPath expression for both cases to my answer. FWIW, +1 from me. Your answer was a few seconds faster than mine anyway.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleXML provides access to your document in form of a nested array. There is no way to place an XPath expression as the array index.

Try something like:

```
$query = "client[@name='foo']/src"; // if name is an attribute
$query = "client[name='foo']/src";  // if name is a child element

foreach ($portfolio->clientGroup[$id]->xpath($query) as $src ) {
   echo $src . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that "name" selects an attribute? Afaik, you need to prefix the name with an "@" sign.

Comment: The darn editor uses the "@" sign as some kind of shortcut for "Blockquote" or such. Everytime I press "@", it starts a new line, and I am forced to create the "@" somewhere else and copy/paste it in. Frustrating. Managed to get it wrong here.