# SimpleXML: Selecting Elements Which Have A Certain Attribute Value

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml, netflix

In an XML document, I have elements which share the same name, but the value of an attribute defines what type of data it is, and I want to select all of those elements which have a certain value from the document.  Do I need to use XPath (and if so, could you suggest the right syntax) or is there a more elegant solution?

Here's some example XML:

```
<object>
  <data type="me">myname</data>
  <data type="you">yourname</data>
  <data type="me">myothername</data>
</object>
```

And I want to select the contents of all `<data>` tags children of `<object>` who's type is `me`.

PS - I'm trying to interface with the Netflix API using PHP - this shouldn't matter for my question, but if you want to suggest a good/better way to do so, I'm all ears.

Comment: X-Ref: [Implementing condition in XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3448005/367456)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try this XPath:

```
/object/data[@type="me"]
```

Which reads as:

- Select (`/`) children of the current element called `object`
- Select (`/`) their children called `data`
- Filter (`[...]`) that list to elements where ...

  - the attribute `type` (the `@` means "attribute")
  - has the text value `me`

So:

```
$myDataObjects = $simplexml->xpath('/object/data[@type="me"]');
```

If `object` is not the root of your document, you might want to use `//object/data[@type="me"]` instead. The `//` means "find all *descendents*" rather than "find all children".

Comment: Can this be done when the element has a default xmlns?

Answer (score 5):

I just made a function to do this for me; it only grabs the first result though. Your mileage may vary.

```
function query_attribute($xmlNode, $attr_name, $attr_value) {
  foreach($xmlNode as $node) { 
    if($node[$attr_name] == $attr_value) {
        return $node;
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
echo query_attribute($MySimpleXmlNode->Customer, "type", "human")->Name;
```

(For the XML below)

```
<Root><Customer type="human"><Name>Sam Jones</name></Customer></Root>
```

Comment: Why not use the XPath Gumbo suggested?  And why use a switch instead of the easier to read `if($node[$attr_name] == $attr_value)`?

Comment: This is a useful example to have, because sometimes you want to incorporate additional logic, so that XPath isn't the best approach.