# Using simplexml to get a node (and its children) by attribute

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Using simplexml, is it possible to get the children of a node based on the parent's attributes. For example, I want to get a list of the variants in myItem1 (output would be small, large)

Here is some psuedo code of what I'm after:

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//family[@name="myItem1"]')->variants->children() as $child) {
    $child->getName()
}
```

(Of course this doesn't work, but hopefully it describes what I'm trying to do.)

Sample XML:

```
<library>
 <family name="myItem1">
   <variants>
    <small>
     ...
    </small>
    <large>
     ...
    </large>    
   </variants>
 </family>
 <family name="myItem2">
   <variants>
    <small>
     ...
    </small>
    <medium>
     ...
    </medium>   
   </variants>
 </family>
</library>
```

Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't really describe what you want to achieve. Please post a sample XML document and a couple of examples of what the "variants" would be.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't format my post correctly. It is showing now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleXML: Selecting Elements Which Have A Certain Attribute Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992450/simplexml-selecting-elements-which-have-a-certain-attribute-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the names of all the children of a given node. There are various way to do it, one of them is to iterate over all the children, like this:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//family[@name="myItem1"]') as $family)
{
    $variants = array();
    foreach ($family->variants->children() as $name => $node)
    {
        $variants[] = $name;
    }

    // in case there are duplicates you can do
    $variants = array_unique($variants);

    var_dump($variants);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following XPath expression:

```
//family[@name="myItem1"]/variants/*
```