# Implementing condition in XPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I have a XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
  <events date="12/12/2010">
    <event>
      <title>JqueryEvent</title>
      <description>
        easily
      </description>
    </event>
  </events>
  <events date="14/12/2011">
    <event>
      <title>automatically onBlur</title>
      <description>
        when a date is selected. For an inline calendar, simply attach the datepicker to a div or span.
      </description>
    </event>
  </events>
</xml>
```

And I am using this Xpath to select the nodes

```
$xml   = simplexml_load_file($file);
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//xml/events');
```

It will select all the nodes.I want to select the nodes based on the date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify the date in the xpath expression,

i.e.

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//xml/events[@date="14/12/2011"]');
```

would select only the last events-node in the example

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//events[@date="14/12/2011"]');
print_r( $nodes );
```

to get the event node below the xml node with the specified date and

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//xml/events[@date]');
print_r( $nodes );
```

to get all event below the xml node nodes having a date attribute. Likewise, use

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//events[contains(@date, "2011")]');
print_r( $nodes );
```

to find all event nodes anywhere in the document with a date attribute containing the string "2011".

On a sidenote, you can use [`simplexml_load_file`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) to load an XML file directly.