# PHP, XML Get a records nodes and values and put them in a JSON Array?

Tags: php, xml, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing condition in XPath and XQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448005/implementing-condition-in-xpath-and-xquery)
>   [PHP convert XML to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830599/php-convert-xml-to-json)

How do i get all child notes from the record which includes Product = Product1
And put them into a JSON array ?

```
<RECORD>
<PROP NAME="Product">
<PVAL><!CDATA[Produkt1]]</PVAL>
<PROP NAME="Value">
<PVAL><!CDATA[10]]</PVAL>
<PROP NAME="Status">
<PVAL><!CDATA[Active]]</PVAL>
</RECORD>
<RECORD>
<PROP NAME="Product">
<PVAL><!CDATA[Produkt2]]</PVAL>
<PROP NAME="Value">
<PVAL><!CDATA[20]]</PVAL>
<PROP NAME="Status">
<PVAL><!CDATA[Active]]</PVAL>
</RECORD>
<RECORD>
<PROP NAME="Product">
<PVAL><!CDATA[Produkt3]]</PVAL>
<PROP NAME="Value">
<PVAL><!CDATA[30]]</PVAL>
<PROP NAME="Status">
<PVAL><!CDATA[Active]]</PVAL>
</RECORD>
```

I need the data for an iPad App, calling something like www.products.com/product.php?Product1

Having the JSON look something like

```
{
 "Product": [
 { "Name":"Product1" , "Value":"10" , "Status":"Active" }
 ]
 }
```

Edit : Solution with XML reader

```
<?php
$z = new XMLReader;
$z->open('products.xml');

$doc = new DOMDocument;

// move to the first <product /> node
while ($z->read() && $z->name !== 'RECORD');

// now that we're at the right depth, hop to the next <product/> until the end of the tree
while ($z->name === 'RECORD')
{

    $node = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($z->expand(), true));


    $strvalue = $node->PROP[6]->PVAL;
    echo $strvalue."<p>" ;

    // go to next <product />
    $z->next('RECORD');
}
?>
```

Comment: There's nothing like `json array`. Do you mean json formatted string?

Comment: To my knodledge there is a thing called JSON Array, but true - it's made of JSON Strings/objects
http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp

Comment: @UlrikVadstrup I was talking about php. [This article](http://lostechies.com/seanbiefeld/2011/10/21/simple-xml-to-json-with-php/) may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, just looking at your XML gives me a headache. Here are a few changes you need to make:

1. If you are going to have multiple  nodes, then you need a wrapper such as  before all of the  nodes and  after all of them.
2. Your PROP node needs a closing tag
3. Your CDATA is misformatted, the proper format is

Here's my example of the newly formatted XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<RECORDS>
    <RECORD>
    <PROP NAME="Product">
        <PVAL><![CDATA[Produkt1]]></PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="Value">
        <PVAL><![CDATA[10]]></PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="Status">
        <PVAL><![CDATA[Active]]></PVAL>
    </PROP>
</RECORD>
<RECORD>
    <PROP NAME="Product">
        <PVAL><![CDATA[Produkt2]]></PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="Value">
        <PVAL><![CDATA[20]]></PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="Status">
        <PVAL><![CDATA[Active]]></PVAL>
    </PROP>
</RECORD>
<RECORD>
    <PROP NAME="Product">
        <PVAL><![CDATA[Produkt3]]></PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="Value">
        <PVAL><![CDATA[30]]></PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="Status">
        <PVAL><![CDATA[Active]]></PVAL>
    </PROP>
</RECORD>
```

Once the XML is formatted properly, I'd use something like SimpleXML to parse it:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $xml_string );
foreach ($xml->RECORD as $record)
{
    if ($record->PROP[0]->PVAL == 'Produkt1')
    {
        echo json_encode( $record );
    }
}
```

I also think you could really benefit from restructuring the entire XML. Something like:

```
<RECORDS>
    <RECORD ID="1">
        <PRODUCT>PRODUCT 1</PRODUCT>
        <VALUE>10</VALUE>
        <STATUS>Active</STATUS>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD ID="2">
        <PRODUCT>PRODUCT 2</PRODUCT>
        <VALUE>20</VALUE>
        <STATUS>Active</STATUS>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD ID="3">
        <PRODUCT>PRODUCT 3</PRODUCT>
        <VALUE>30</VALUE>
        <STATUS>Active</STATUS>
    </RECORD>
</RECORDS>
```

So then the PHP would be like:

```
foreach ($xml->RECORD as $record)
{
    $attr = $record->attributes();
    if( $attr['ID'] == '1' )
    {
        echo json_encode( $record );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for a constuctive answer :-)
Unfortunatly i'm not the one making the xml file, i have just been told to drag out info.
I will make my own example and use your code to get him to change things.
I will test later - Thanks a million :-D

Comment: hmn.....I'm for sure on the right track. When i created a "small" test file, everything works as planned. However my XML file is 100 mb, so i guess i should use XMLreader instead of SimpleXML. Anybody can give me a little help ? writing Jason's code for xmlreader ?

Comment: How do i read out the "Name" Value - like "Status" ?