# How to get specific value from xml according parameter attribute?

Tags: php, simplexml

XML file contains:

```
<list1>
  <dzial>
    <ofert>
      <param name="surname" type="text">Something</param>
      <param name="number" type="text">4234-343-3</param>
    </ofert>
  </dzial>
</list1>
```

If I want to get "surname" parameter then I can use this code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

if ($xml->list1[0]->dzial[0]->ofert[0]->param[0]=="Something") 
  echo "works!";
```

But I want to do it in different way. I want to select parameter according its attribute `name="surname"`. How can I do that?

```
echo $xml->list1[0]->dzial[0]->ofert[0]->param[???];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//param[@name="surname"]');

if (!empty($nodes)) {
    echo $nodes[0];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use xpath, as explained in this answer:
[SimpleXML: Selecting Elements Which Have A Certain Attribute Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992450/simplexml-selecting-elements-which-have-a-certain-attribute-value)

```
$simplexml->xpath('/object/data[@attribute="value"]');
```