# Simplexml get node by attribute

Tags: php, simplexml

I've got xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xml>
<opis lang="en">My text</opis>
<opis lang="cz">My text2</opis>
</xml>
```

I want to get "My text2" - so a node where attribute lang is "cz":

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($fileName);
$result = $xml->xpath('//xml/opis[@lang="cz"]')
```

but instead of value I get:

```
array(1) (
  [0] => SimpleXMLElement object {
    @attributes => array(1) (
      [lang] => (string) cz
    )
  }
))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleXML: Selecting Elements Which Have A Certain Attribute Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992450/simplexml-selecting-elements-which-have-a-certain-attribute-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using DomDocument:

```
$xml = new DomDocument;
$xml->load('yourFile');
$xpath = new DomXpath($xml);

foreach ($xpath->query('//xml/opis[@lang="cz"]') as $rowNode) {
  echo $rowNode->nodeValue; // will be 'this item'
}
```

Comment: -1: OP asked for SimpleXML, which does it equally (if not even simplier). Also both - SimpleXML or DOMDocument - a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the value like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($fileName);
$result = $xml->xpath('//xml/opis[@lang="cz"]');
foreach($result as $res) {
   echo $res;
}
```