# PHP/XML - how to read multible sub's

Tags: xml, simplexml, php

I need a to create an array with all the subject values in this XML file.
The ISIN list seems to work fine (the first property value), but subject values does not work.

I would like to end up with a array looking something like this:

```
$Companys = array ( [0]  => array ( "isin" => "DK0010247014","company" => "AAB"),
                    [1]  => array ( "isin" => "DK0015250344","company" => "ALM BRAND"),
                    [2]  => array ( "isin" => "DK0015998017","company" => "BAVARIAN NORDI"),
                    [3]  => array ( "isin" => "DK0010259027","company" => "DFDS"),
                    [4]  => array ( "isin" => "DK0010234467","company" => "FLSMIDTH & CO"),
                );
```

This is an example of one of the files i am trying to parse:

```
<doc>
    <id>123456</id>
    <version>4.0</version>
    <consnr>7861</consnr>
    <doctype>10</doctype>
    <dest>99</dest>
    <created>2013-05-15 14:18:16</created>
    <source>Direkt-DK</source>
    <language>DA</language>
    <texttype>This is a type</texttype>
    <premium>False</premium>
    <header>This is a header</header>
    <text>
        <para format="Text">This is a paragraph</para>
        <para format="Text">This is a paragraph</para>
        <para format="Text">This is a paragraph</para>
        <para format="Text">This is a paragraph</para>
        <para format="Text"/>
        <para format="Text">This is a paragraph</para>
        <para format="Byline"/>
        <para format="Byline">contents og the by line</para>
        <para format="Byline"/>
        <para format="Byline"/>
    </text>
    <subjects>
        <subject value="AAB" weight="Main">
            <property value="DK0010247014" type2="isin" type1="identificator"/>
            <property value="CSE:AAB" type2="ticker" type1="identificator"/>
            <property type1="sector" type2="GICS" type3="1" value="25"/>
            <property type1="sector" type2="GICS" type3="2" value="2530"/>
            <property type1="sector" type2="GICS" type3="3" value="253010"/>
            <property type1="sector" type2="GICS" type3="4" value="25301030"/>
        </subject>
        <subject value="ALM BRAND" weight="Main">
            <property value="DK0015250344" type2="isin" type1="identificator"/>
            <property value="CSE:ALMB" type2="ticker" type1="identificator"/>
            <property type1="sector" type2="GICS" type3="1" value="40"/>
            <property type1="sector" type2="GICS" type3="2" value="4030"/>
            <property type1="sector" type2="GICS" type3="3" value="403010"/>
            <property type1="sector" type2="GICS" type3="4" value="40301040"/>
        </subject>
        <subject value="BAVARIAN NORDI" weight="Main">
            <property value="DK0015998017" type2="isin" type1="identificator"/>
            <property value="CSE:BAVA" type2="ticker" type1="identificator"/>
            <property type1="sector" type2="GICS" type3="1" value="35"/>
            <property type1="sector" type2="GICS" type3="2" value="3520"/>
            <property type1="sector" type2="GICS" type3="3" value="352010"/>
            <property type1="sector" type2="GICS" type3="4" value="35201010"/>
        </subject>
        <subject value="DFDS" weight="Main">
            <property value="DK0010259027" type2="isin" type1="identificator"/>
            <property value="CSE:DFDS" type2="ticker" type1="identificator"/>
            <property type1="sector" type2="GICS" type3="1" value="20"/>
            <property type1="sector" type2="GICS" type3="2" value="2030"/>
            <property type1="sector" type2="GICS" type3="3" value="203030"/>
            <property type1="sector" type2="GICS" type3="4" value="20303010"/>
        </subject>
        <subject value="FLSMIDTH & CO" weight="Main">
            <property value="DK0010234467" type2="isin" type1="identificator"/>
            <property value="CSE:FLS" type2="ticker" type1="identificator"/>
            <property type1="sector" type2="GICS" type3="1" value="20"/>
            <property type1="sector" type2="GICS" type3="2" value="2010"/>
            <property type1="sector" type2="GICS" type3="3" value="201030"/>
            <property type1="sector" type2="GICS" type3="4" value="20103010"/>
        </subject>
    </subjects>
</doc>
```

Script:

```
<?
    foreach($xmlObj->subjects->subject as $b ){
        $isin = $b->property;
        $company = $b->attributes();
        #$company = $b->attributes()->value;
        If($isin && $isinlist == 'null') $isinlist = $isin['value'];
        ElseIf ($isin && $isinlist) $isinlist .= ','.$isin['value'];
        If($company && $companylist == 'null') $companylist = $company['value'];
        ElseIf ($company && $companylist) $companylist .= ','.$company['value'];
        var_dump($company->value[0]);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please reduce your problem to the *really* minimum needed to demonstrate the issue. To trigger that error you don't need all that XML nor all that PHP code. Keep it compact when you create a question here on site. That way you will probably already find the cause or a solution (but you can still ask about what you do not understand (hint)) and also you will get better answers.

Comment: I need the values in each subject like "FLSMIDTH & CO" - to be parsed as a string of values, comma seperated. I will edit my question, to make it more spefic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem you've got is to find the child-element based on an attributes value. As there are multiple children with the same element name, you can not differ on the name alone.

In your concrete example the *property* child based on the attribute *type2="isin"*.

This is either possible by making use of Xpath (this website already has a lot of Q&A material about that, for example [*SimpleXML: Selecting Elements Which Have A Certain Attribute Value*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/992450/367456)) or by extending `SimpleXMLElement` with a function  that just does it:

```
class MyElement extends SimpleXMLElement
{
    public function getChildByAttributeValue($name, $value) {
        foreach($this as $child)
        {
            if ($value === (string) $child[$name]) {
                return $child;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use the `MyElement` *instead* of the `SimpleXMLElement`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer, 'MyElement');
                                      ###########
```

and just map your values to an array:

```
$map = function(MyElement $subject) {
    return [
        (string) $subject['value'],
        (string) $subject->getChildByAttributeValue('type2', 'isin')['value'],
    ];
};

print_r(array_map($map, $xml->xpath('//subject')));
```

Given that `$buffer` is the XML you have provided in question (and the encoding error removed), this creates the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => AAB
            [1] => DK0010247014
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ALM BRAND
            [1] => DK0015250344
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => BAVARIAN NORDI
            [1] => DK0015998017
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => DFDS
            [1] => DK0010259027
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => FLSMIDTH & CO
            [1] => DK0010234467
        )

)
```

The full code example ([Online Demo](http://eval.in/32721)):

```
class MyElement extends SimpleXMLElement
{
    public function getChildByAttributeValue($name, $value) {
        foreach($this as $child)
        {
            if ($value === (string) $child[$name]) {
                return $child;
            }
        }
    }
}

$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer, 'MyElement');

$map = function(MyElement $subject) {
    return [
        (string) $subject['value'],
        (string) $subject->getChildByAttributeValue('type2', 'isin')['value'],
    ];
};

print_r(array_map($map, $xml->xpath('//subject')));
```