# Read and take value of XML attributes

Tags: php, xml

I am stock with this XML problem, I have a XML file that I browse to find values.  Everything is working fine, I can read on all the child nodes, but  I am stuck on this section.  The XML portion containing photos are all the same name of the node, except for an attribute, how can I specify how to browse according to this and take the filename value of each of them

```
XML 
...
<Engine>
            <Fuel>Unleaded</Fuel>
            <Cylinders>4</Cylinders>
            <Induction>Normally aspirated</Induction>
          </Engine>
          <Photo order="1">
            <Filename>http://usedcarpics.s3.amazonaws.com/514SPINELLITOYOTA2/b5092588_2.jpg</Filename>
          </Photo>
          <Photo order="2">
            <Filename>http://usedcarpics.s3.amazonaws.com/514SPINELLITOYOTA2/b5092588_3.jpg</Filename>
          </Photo>
          <Photo order="3">
            <Filename>http://usedcarpics.s3.amazonaws.com/514SPINELLITOYOTA2/b5092588_4.jpg</Filename>
          </Photo>
          <Photo order="4">
            <Filename>http://usedcarpics.s3.amazonaws.com/514SPINELLITOYOTA2/b5092588_5.jpg</Filename>
          </Photo>
          <Photo order="5">
            <Filename>http://usedcarpics.s3.amazonaws.com/514SPINELLITOYOTA2/b5092588_6.jpg</Filename>

...
```

In my php file, I have this code that help me find the values:

```
$import->stock_no =(string)$item->Invoice->Vehicle->VehicleStock;           

$import->image1 =(string)$item->Invoice->Vehicle->Photo->attributes(order="1")->Filename;
```

Of course it doesn't work, how can I browse all the photo nodes( I have 8 pictures I need to take the values from)

I want to have $import->image1 = (filename  in the attibutes of pohoto 1), sames for image 2, 3, etc.

Thank you.

Comment: `attributes(order="1")` is not exactly valid PHP anyways...

Comment: I understand that, but how can I select photo with attribute called order="1"  than order="2", ... until I reach order ="8"

Comment: For example using XPATH or just a loop over elements.

Comment: looping thru, would be something like this:  $import->image1 =(string)$item->Invoice->Vehicle->Photo->Filename;    $import->image2 =(string)$item->Invoice->Vehicle->Photo->Filename;    $import->image3 =(string)$item->Invoice->Vehicle->Photo->Filename;    $import->image4 =(string)$item->Invoice->Vehicle->Photo->Filename;

Comment: No, a loop is either `foreach`, `while`, or `for`.

Comment: [XPath](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) is your friend, `//Photo[@order="1"]/Filename`, or if you want them all loop through `//Photo[@order]/Filename`..

Comment: I do not understand.  Ok for foareach, this I tried and it's not working for me.  But Xpath, how do I write this,   $import->image1 = //Photo[@order="1"]/fimename  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to achieve is (first of all) possible by using an xpath query. You want to access a child-node based on an attribute value. The better reference questions in SimpleXML are:

- [Implementing condition in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3448005/367456)
- [SimpleXML get element content based on attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736417/367456)

It's also since some days when the suggestion was given to extend form `SimpleXMLElement` to provide a utility function to actually do that with an easy interface:

- [PHP/XML - how to read multible sub's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16921116/367456)
- [simplexml_load_file - redundant element with empty value is converted to new SimpleXMLElement Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17404930/367456)

However your case is a little different because of the syntax you suggest:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer, 'MySimpleXMLElement');

echo $xml->Vehicle->Photo->attribute("order", "1")->Filename;

// prints "http://usedcarpics.s3.amazonaws.com/514SPINELLITOYOTA2/b5092588_2.jpg"
```

Instead of using an ordinary `SimpleXMLElement` this example uses an extended one named (exemplary) `MySimpleXMLElement`. It runs an XPath query inside based on the input parameters and based on the parent element it operates on (here being a `Photo` element):

```
/**
 * Class MySimpleXMLElement
 *
 * Example of how to magically access named child-nodes based
 * on an attribute value of theirs.
 */
class MySimpleXMLElement extends SimpleXMLElement
{
    public function attribute($name, $value) {

        $nodes = $this->xpath(
            sprintf('../%s[@%s = "%s"]', $this->getName(), $name, $value)
        );

        return $nodes ? $nodes[0] : NULL;
    }
}
```

This new `MySimpleXMLElement::attribute()` method (sorry [`attributes()` was already in use](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.attributes)) is then available on every node. So have fun.

Naturally you can also write it this way:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);

echo $xml->Vehicle->xpath('Photo[@order="1"]')[0]->Filename;

// prints "http://usedcarpics.s3.amazonaws.com/514SPINELLITOYOTA2/b5092588_2.jpg"
```

the extended SimpleXMLElement is mainly for convenience reasons. And it's probably more easy to debug in case you're not fluent with Xpath yet.

Last time I extended SimpleXMLElement on Stackoverflow was in the said [answer to the *"simplexml_load_file - redundant element with empty value is converted to new SimpleXMLElement Object"* question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17404930/367456).

Comment: I get an error  if I write it like you did.    unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: I assume for the last example? If so, that is because you're probably using PHP 5.3 or 5.2 which are end of live. Upgrade to PHP 5.4 minimum *or* change to older array-access with the help of an additional function or variable. `$nodes = $xml->Vehicle->xpath('Photo[@order="1"]'); echo $nodes[0]->Filename;` - Also take care that I use the shortened example XML, so you paths to the elements are likely to be different then I have in the answer

Comment: Here is an online demo: https://eval.in/36953 - It also shows at the very end that - as the images are already ordered - you can also access them by their zero-based index with square brackets.

Comment: I have my code working,  I used:  echo $xml->Vehicle->Photo[0]->Filename, "\n";  and I get the image just like I wanted.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I had in there as the last example. Sometimes it's easier than you first think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <?php
    $xml = '<Engine>
                <Fuel>Unleaded</Fuel>
                <Cylinders>4</Cylinders>
                <Induction>Normally aspirated</Induction>
            </Engine>
            <Photo order="1">
                <Filename>http://usedcarpics.s3.amazonaws.com/514SPINELLITOYOTA2/b5092588_2.jpg</Filename>
              </Photo>
              <Photo order="2">
                <Filename>http://usedcarpics.s3.amazonaws.com/514SPINELLITOYOTA2/b5092588_3.jpg</Filename>
              </Photo>';

    $xml="<Wraper>".$xml."</Wraper>";
    $parse=new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

    echo "Engine Fuel:".$parse->Engine->Fuel;
    echo "<br/>Engine Cylinders:".$parse->Engine->Cylinders;
    echo "Photos<br/>";
    foreach ($parse->Photo as $photo)
    {

        echo "<br/>Photo Order: ".$photo->attributes();
        echo "<br/>Photo URL: ".$photo->Filename;
        echo "<hr/>";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

sweet and simple with `xpath`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

$photos = $xml->xpath("//Photo"); // select all Photo nodes and their children in an array

foreach ($photos as $photo)
    echo "order: $photo[order], file: $photo->Filename<br />"; // simple output
```

see it working: http://3v4l.org/SJmEg

Comment: @maphaneuf click the blue `eval` button below the code, then see the generated output below that.

Comment: almost, I had to change project, will return to this this afternoon.

Comment: I actually have a working solution, I tryed this morning and It works. Here is what I have working, solution provided by hakre

Comment: https://eval.in/36953    I just used the echo $xml->Vehicle->Photo[0]->Filename, "\n";  and it works because my iamge are all already in the right order.    THank you to all