# php - convert xml (milliseconds?) to readable date

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, integer-overflow

I have an `XML` file I am parsing and then inserting into my database using `PHP`. The date nodes however are in a weird `XML` format that I believed to be milliseconds. My attempts to convert this so far have been unsuccessful and I was hoping someone could point out my error.

**XML**

```
<est__start>1335744000000</est__start>
<est__end>1342742400000</est__end>
```

Which was this much more readable date before being converted

```
<est__start> 04-30-2012 </est__start>
<est__end> 07-20-2012 </est__end>
```

**PHP**

```
$start = $data->est__start;
if (empty($start)) {
    $start = '';
} else {
    $start = intval($start);            
    $seconds = $start / 1000;
    $start = date("d-m-Y", $seconds);
}
$end = $data->est__start;
if (empty($end)) {
    $end = '';
} else {
    $end = intval($end);            
    $seconds = $end / 1000;
    $end = date("d-m-Y", $end);
}
```

The end result however is always something similar to this

```
25-01-1970
```

and I need it to look like it did before the conversion. Like this

```
04-30-2012
```

Since I'm not handling the original date conversion when it goes into the XML file I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I *guess* quickly that `intval` is standing in your way. `echo PHP_INT_MAX;` to learn about what the system you're using does offer you. It will cap the seconds to 32 bit signed max.

Comment: @hakre Although the question is related to converting Unix timestamps, the OP's problem is related to how he wrote the code and the finite size of integers.  This is a good question.

Comment: Yes I was quick with the dupe, you need to use floats instead of casting to in. I also put this in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18367563/367456 and it's the standard way to deal with it on 32 bit system in PHP. The precision should be OK for these cases otherwise this needs bcmath or gmp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP uses the string value of the [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/class.SimpleXMLElement) if you use it in `intval` or as well directly in numeric calculations (which also cast to int).

As I already commented, my first quick guess was right, it truncates the number than to the maximum integer available on a 32 bit system signed (2<sup>31</sup> − 1) (I guess you're using one) which results in:

```
2 147 483 647
25-01-1970
```

This number btw. is sort of somewhat *famous* and has it's own Wikipedia page: [2147483647](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647).

Instead use the `floatval` function, it gives you what you're looking for:

```
$seconds = floatval($start) / 1000;
echo date("d-m-Y", $seconds); # prints "30-04-2012"
```

*Bonus:* Here is some code you might find handy to have the conversion code in a central place and easily make use of:

```
/**
 * Class MySimpleXMLElement
 *
 * Extended SimpleXMLElement
 */
class MySimpleXMLElement extends SimpleXMLElement
{
    /**
     * @param string $format
     *
     * @return bool|string
     */
    public function getDateFromMilliseconds($format = "d-m-Y") {
        return date("d-m-Y", floatval($this) / 1000);
    }

    /**
     * @param DateTimeZone $timezone
     *
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function createDateTimeFromMilliseconds(DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL) {
        return new DateTime('@' . (floatval($this) / 1000), $timezone);
    }
}

$data  = new MySimpleXMLElement('<r><est__start>1335744000000</est__start><est__end>1342742400000</est__end></r>');
/* @var $start MySimpleXMLElement */
$start = $data->est__start;

echo $start->getDateFromMilliseconds(), "\n"; # prints "30-04-2012"

echo $start->createDateTimeFromMilliseconds()->format('Y-m-d'); # prints "2012-04-30"
```

It works by extending from SimpleXMLElement and adding the date-creation functions, here one for a formatted string and for more advanced datetime operations one that gives back a [`DateTime` object](http://php.net/class.DateTime).

Last time I extended SimpleXMLElement on Stackoverflow was in an [answer to the *"How to replace XML node with SimpleXMLElement PHP"* question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17671451/367456).

Comment: this makes a lot of sense, but when I run the code with `floatval` rather than `date` it throws an error: `floatval() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given`

Comment: well not rather than date, rather than intval :) Look the example, I have not replaced date().

Comment: indeed sir, however the problem remains, I find it kind of odd. I am only passing 1 param. Why would it think it's two?

Comment: ha, I spotted my goof. Silly little typos, get you everytime. It works, thanks. I will be accepting this answer as it is the most complete

Comment: @i_me_mine: Well, mistakes happen. I also added you some bonus.

Comment: awesome, thanks. Hopefully this helps people in the future as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `intval` but the numbers are too large for `int`.
Just use:

```
date("m-d-Y", 1335744000000 / 1000); // 04-30-2012
```

Comment: thanks, im checking it out now, although this makes perfect sense

Comment: You might also check the PHP constant `PHP_INT_MAX` to be sure.  Note that the results will vary depending on the OS of the server running PHP (32 bit versus 64 bit).

Comment: Depends on your PHP_INT_SIZE ini. Try `echo PHP_INT_SIZE;` Mine is 8 and those numbers are processed just fine.

Answer (score 1):

you are not passing seconds in the second run:

[image]

Comment: very nice catch, not the root of this problem, but definitely would of been once I had this figured out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Possible UTC, and switch day and month:

```
echo gmdate('m-d-Y',1342742400000 / 1000);
```

Result:

```
07-20-2012
```

Comment: thanks, im checking it out now, although this makes perfect sense