# Get array in object xml (simplexml_load_string)

Tags: php, arrays, xml, simplexml

I have a `$xml` looks like this

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [Total] => 450
            [Count] => 4
            [Start] => 0
        )

    [Code] => 0
    [Item] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Person.P_Id] => 14845
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Person.P_Id] => 14844
                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Person.P_Id] => 14837
                )

            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Person.P_Id] => 14836
                )

        )
)
```

Now I want to get the array `Item` to merge with another array, but when I try `$xml->Item`, I only get the first element of this array (which is `14845`). When I use `count($xml->Item)`, it returns the true value (which is 4). Did I do something wrong to get the whole array `Item`?

Comment: you need to iterate in `->Item`, where are the codes anyway? you forgot to add them in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say whether you want the items as SimpleXMLElements, or just the `Person.P_Id` values. To get the objects, you can use [`xpath`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to get an array:

```
$itemobjs = $xml->xpath('//Item');
print_r($itemobjs);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Person.P_Id] => 14845
        )    
    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Person.P_Id] => 14844
        )    
    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Person.P_Id] => 14837
        )    
    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Person.P_Id] => 14836
        )    
)
```

If you just want the `Person.P_Id` values, you can then iterate that array using `array_map`:

```
$items = array_map(function ($v) { return (string)$v->{'Person.P_Id'}; }, $itemobjs);
print_r($items);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 14845
    [1] => 14844
    [2] => 14837
    [3] => 14836
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/uelbR)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is what I want `$itemobjs = $xml->xpath('//Item');`

Comment: I have one more question that I wonder if it's hard. I want to assign another array (with the same format) to the `$xml->Item` array, can I do it? As normal code, I would do something like this `$xml->Item = $new_array`, but in this case, I can't

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace the items in the array? That isn't possible in SimpleXML directly, but you can do it using `DOM`. See this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661167/how-to-replace-xml-node-with-simplexmlelement-php

Comment: If you have problems implementing that code, write up a new question (referring back to that one).