# PHP: get parent node where child = 'value'

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I have this xml file:

```
<friends>
    <friend>
        <name>xxx</name>
        <pays>France</pays>
    </friend>
    <friend>
        <name>yyy</name>
        <country>France</country>
    </friend>
    <friend>
        <name>zzz</name>
        <country>USA</country>
    </friend>
</friends>
```

To get my data, I am using this php code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('friends.xml');
$friendsXML = $xml->friend;
```

Which works fine, but returns all of the friends.

Now I want to retrieve only friends who are from France:

```
country = 'france'.
```

Can anyone help me doing that?

Comment: simple xpath: `//country[text()='france']/..`

Comment: Or perhaps better duplicate: [php simplexml get a specific item based on the value of a field](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17537909/367456)

Comment: Or perhaps the even better duplicate: [Implementing condition in XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3448005/367456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use XPath for things like this. Try:

```
 $res =  $xml->xpath('friend[country = "france"]');
 echo $res[0];
```