# PHP - loop xml for attribute

Tags: php, xml, foreach, simplexml

How do I loop through this xml and get the attribute `href` of the second `<link>` tag? The one with the attribute `rel="enclosure"`

This is the XML;

```
  <entry>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/dax/5495234222/in/set-756787626064123145/"/>
    <link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5012/5485746322_9821c561bf_b.jpg" />
  </entry>
```

This is the php script so far:

```
<?php
foreach ($feed->entry as $item) {
    $photo = $item->link['href'];
    ?>
    <div class="">
    <a href="<?php print $photo; ?>" class="colorbox-load"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php print $photo; ?>"></a>
    </div>

<?php
}
?>
```

This is working apart form the fact it prints the `href` of the first `<link>` which is not the one I need.

Comment: You do so by choosing the href of the link with the enclosure rel(ation): `$photo = $item->xpath('link[@rel="enclosure"]/@href')[0];` - the position (first, second) is a too weak criteria when you need the enclosure. See as well [the answer by @michi](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22121574/367456).

Comment: Also possible duplicate of: [SimpleXML: Selecting Elements Which Have A Certain Attribute Value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/992450/367456)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `simplexml` and `xpath` to select an attribute based on another attribute.
`xpath` is like an SQL-query for XML:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

$link = (string)$xml->xpath("/entry/link[@rel = 'enclosure']/@href")[0];
```

The `[0]` at the end of line 2 requires PHP >= 5.4. If you are on a lower version, either update or do:

```
$link = $xml->xpath("/entry/link[@rel = 'enclosure']/@href");
$link = (string)$link[0];
```

The `xpath`-expression selects the `href`-attributes of all `<link>`-nodes that have an attribute `rel='enclosure'` and have `<entry>` as their parent in an `array` of `simplexml Elements`.

The code above will select only the 1st element of the `array` and transform it to `string`.

see it working: https://eval.in/107641

If you rather want to use the `foreach`-loop, you need to check for the `rel-attribute`like this:

```
foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) {

    if ($entry->link['rel'] == 'enclosure') {

        echo "This is the link: " . $entry->link['href'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to parse your XML:

```php
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
  <entry>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/dax/5495234222/in/set-756787626064123145/"/>
    <link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5012/5485746322_9821c561bf_b.jpg" />
  </entry>
XML;

$links = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo $links->link[1]['href'];
```