# Getting values from an XML string in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have this XML file and i need to extract the values of USER_NAME and USER_ID and IP from it. I loaded the XML into SimpleXML using:

```
$xmlObj=new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstring);
```

But I don't now what to do after that..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>
   <response>
      <state>
         <code>1</code>
      </state>
        <userinformationlist>
           <userinformation>
              <attribute key="USER_NAME">Charles</attribute>
              <attribute key="USER_ID">88477299101</attribute>
              <attribute key="IP">127.0.0.1</attribute>
              <attribute key="CCR_UUID" />
           </userinformation>
        </userinformationlist>
     </response>
</content>
```

Comment: The XML seems to be missing a `</content>` in the end. Is this on purpose or accidental? Is this really relevant?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, </content> is now added

Comment: Really the simplest of tutorials about php and xml would explain this. Do you really think it will help your solution-finding skills, when you ask such questions?

Comment: Actually i've tried plenty of things but none of them worked. Since you seem to know the answer, it would be wonderful to help me out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example using the [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) extension, particularly [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php), rather than SimpleXML as I find SimpleXML on the whole unpalatable.

#### Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xmlstring);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$name = $xpath->evaluate('string(//attribute[@key="USER_NAME"])');
$id   = $xpath->evaluate('string(//attribute[@key="USER_ID"])');
$ip   = $xpath->evaluate('string(//attribute[@key="IP"])');
echo "$name\t$id\t$ip\n";
```

#### Output:

```
Charles 88477299101 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! I was unable to get it to work with SimpleXML no matter what i tried.. :( Cheers!

Comment: @MarcelEmblazoned: Then this was what you were looking but (not search ing ;)) for: [SimpleXML: Selecting Elements Which Have A Certain Attribute Value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/992450/367456)