# PHP Last.fm Get Largest Image for an Artist

Tags: php, simplexml

I have the following code

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Metallica&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026");
    $artistTag= $xml->artist->children();
    $largeImage = $artistTag[7];
    echo '<img src="'.$largeImage.'" />';     
?>
```

This will target the 7th node - however the 7th node might not exist so this won't work. Is there anyway to specifically target the large, extralarge or mega nodes?

Example XML

```
<lfm status="ok">
<artist>
<name>Metallica</name>
<mbid>65f4f0c5-ef9e-490c-aee3-909e7ae6b2ab</mbid>
<url>http://www.last.fm/music/Metallica</url>
<image size="small">
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/34s/c14fdad46a5c423f86a683501c163c99.png
</image>
<image size="medium">
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/64s/c14fdad46a5c423f86a683501c163c99.png
</image>
<image size="large">
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/174s/c14fdad46a5c423f86a683501c163c99.png
</image>
<image size="extralarge">
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/300x300/c14fdad46a5c423f86a683501c163c99.png
</image>
<image size="mega">
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/c14fdad46a5c423f86a683501c163c99.png
</image>
<image size="">
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/arQ/c14fdad46a5c423f86a683501c163c99.png
</image>
```

So if mega doesn't exist, go for extralarge, if that doesn't exist, go to large etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SimpleXML: Selecting Elements Which Have A Certain Attribute Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992450/simplexml-selecting-elements-which-have-a-certain-attribute-value)

Comment: That seems to bring back an array not containing the image

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a duplicate of : [SimpleXML: Selecting Elements Which Have A Certain Attribute Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992450/simplexml-selecting-elements-which-have-a-certain-attribute-value)

Here is what I would think for your particular case:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Metallica&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026");
$largeImage = $xml->xpath('/lfm/artist/image[@size="mega"]')[0];
echo '<img src="'.$largeImage.'" />';     
?>
```

Comment: PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\lastfm.php on line 4. Also if I do use print_r the array is empty. The XML is http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Metallica&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026

Comment: Hey there pee2pee- the XPath was incorrect, didn't include the base. I've edited it, hopefully that works for you. Again, the other stack overflow thread is still relevant, just google xpaths until you understand it?

Comment: It still only brings back an empty array

Comment: Alrighty- good luck man, I hope you can figure out the xpath. I provided the answer to your question, just not the code for your particular use case. (In any case, this is a duplicate) I don't mind if you don't bother choosing an answer for this, no worries yo.

Comment: I've tried all combinations and none of it works - baffling

Comment: I'm happy you figured it out! That's awesome. It's a bummer that you're trying to be so specific with your questions and answers man... SO really isn't for specific code, it's for concepts. This should assist someone in the future with a similar issue, and surely their issue won't be exactly what you've got.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Metallica&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026");
$largeImage = $xml->xpath('/lfm/artist/image[@size="mega"]')[0];
echo '<img src="'.$largeImage.'" />'; 
?>
```