# PHP - Get image url from RSS feed

Tags: php, function

I have to get the url (not the link) of an image that I'm getting from an rss feed in PHP. I know that if I want to get the link (not url) of one of the feed titles I have to use `$feed->channel->item->link;` but what if I want to get the image url (not the link) of the feed item and insert it into a variable for later use? maybe `$feed->channel->image->url;` - i used this but nothing works.

This is what I used to get the feed.

```
function get_google_image($image){
{        $intento=0;
         $imagealt=get_the_title(); //its wordpress
         $image=get_the_title();
                 $words = explode(" ", $image);
                 $imagetitle = implode(" ", array_splice($words, 0, 2));
                 $image = implode(" ", array_splice($words, 0, 2));
         $image=str_replace(" ","+",$image);
         while (!$feed=simplexml_load_file("http://obsrv.com/General/ImageFeed.aspx?'$image'")){
                 $attempt+=1;
                 if ($attempt>5) break;
                 print "Retry".$attempt."<br>";
                 }
                 $imagelink=$feed->channel->image->url; //Here is the problem, this variable finally gets empty and i want it to be the url of the image so i can post it with html later in the line below
                 echo '<img title="' . $imagetitle . '" alt="' . $imagealt . '" src="' . $imagelink . '"/>';
}}
```

The feed is http://obsrv.com/General/ImageFeed.aspx? (here the variable with the keyword for the image search) I want to get the first item from the rss feed list (the first image because every rss post has a only one image and also has a this image as an file attached to the post if it that helps you to help me). So I want to get this image and take out the url into a variable so then I can make a html code for posting an image.

```
echo '<img title="' . $imagetitle . '" alt="' . $imagealt . '" src="' . $imagelink . '"/>';
```

Comment: What's with the single-quotes around `$image` in the feed URL?

Comment: See this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551246/attribute-value-selection-in-simplexml, it explains how to get attribute values from a simplexml node

Comment: Can you post the xml from that feed? It's not directly accessible on the url posted.

Comment: I thought the quotes are all wright, are they wrong?

Comment: this is an accessible feed url obsrv.com/General/ImageFeed.aspx?linux

Answer (score 1):

You several issue in your code:

1. **From [the help page](http://techmusings.blogspot.com/2009/01/watching-world.html), I can see that you supplied the wrong URL structure:**

   ```
   "http://obsrv.com/General/ImageFeed.aspx?'$image'"
   ```

   It should be:

   ```
   "http://obsrv.com/General/ImageFeed.aspx?q=" . $image . ""
   ```
2. **I think there's bug in your code:**

   First, you set `$image` as function parameter to `get_google_image($image)`
   And then you set `$image` taken from wordpress's function. I don't know if this is your intended method.
3. **This code is also buggy:**

   ```
   $image=str_replace(" ","+",$image);
   ```

   I think this is what you looking for:

   ```
   $image = urlencode($image);
   ```
4. **Another issue is, you supplied `simplexml_load_file()` with URL.**

   **UPDATE**: Phil pointed out that `simplexml_load_file()` does work with URL, if fopen HTTP wrapper is enabled. But, if it's disable, you can use this code as a workaround:

   ```
   $raw_html = file_get_contents( "http://obsrv.com/General/ImageFeed.aspx?q=$image" );
   $feed=simplexml_load_string( $raw_html );
   ```

Comment: +1 Except for point #4. `simplexml_load_file()` can accept a URL argument if the fopen HTTP wrapper is enabled (which it usually is)

Comment: Ok, but that was not my question.
When I use  $image=str_replace(" ","+",$image);  its because I want to replace any space in the tittle for a +.
And I do not understand what you said about the $image parameter.
Thanks...

Comment: point #1 is OBVIOUSLY related. Because, without it you can't even get the RSS. Maybe number 2 also, but that depending on what you really want to do with that code.